# Busca com LIKE ou MATCH..AGAINST em duas colunas

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um sistema de classificados onde faço uma busca com PHP e MySQL usando `LIKE` em dois campos:

```
campo1 like '' or campo2 like ''
```

O problema é quando procuro por algo do tipo: "Carro verde" ele não exibe nada por "carro" estar contido no campo 1 e "verde" no campo 2, ou até mesmo carro vir com uma palavra no meio antes do "Verde".

Alguém poderia me dar uma dica de como melhorar essa busca?

**Tentei usar:**

```
SELECT description, title , MATCH ( title, description ) AGAINST ( '$busca' ) AS Score    
FROM qtc_ads WHERE MATCH ( title, description ) AGAINST ( '$busca' )
ORDER BY Score DESC LIMIT 50
```

Porém o MySQL me informa que os campos não dão suporte a esse tipo de busca e nem sei se essa é a melhor forma.

**SQL que uso atualmente para buscar em meu sistema:**

```
SELECT * FROM `qtc_ads` AS `qtc_ad` WHERE `status` = 1 AND `title` LIKE '%l200%' (1)
```

Comment: Posta a SQL que está utilizando.

Comment: Você está tentando usar busca FULLTEXT, o que parece ser um bom caminho. Mas para isso funcionar, as colunas em questão precisam ter índices FULLTEXT. Era sobre iso o erro que você mencionou? Seria bom postar a mensagem exata.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `qtc_ads` AS `qtc_ad` WHERE `status` = 1 AND `title` LIKE '%carro%'

Comment: Você quer procurar por "carro" no campo1 e campo2 e "verde" no campo1 e campo2?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Uma possibilidade um pouco trabalhosa, mas com um resultado mais completo, é usar o PHP para dividir a sua pesquisa em palavras separadas, e gerar a clausula WHERE pra você:

```
<?php

   $pesquisa = 'carro verde amassado ';

   // Aqui você pode juntar vários campos no concat.
   $campo = 'CONCAT( title, " ", description, " ", author)';
   // Ou usar um só, mas nesse caso talvez compense um LIKE tradicional
   // $campo = 'title';

   $palavras = explode( ' ', $pesquisa ); // dividindo as palavras pelo espaço
   $palavras = array_filter($palavras); // eliminando ítens vazios

   $where = '';
   $cola = 'WHERE ';

   foreach ($palavras as $palavra) {
      $palavra = trim($palavra); //Removendo espaços em branco
      $palavra = mysql_real_escape_string($palavra); //Precisa da conexao com o banco!
      $where .= $cola.campo.' LIKE "%'.$palavra.'%" ';
      $cola = 'AND ';
   }

   echo htmlentities( $where );
?>
```

E o resultado será:

```
WHERE
   CONCAT( title, " ", description, " ", author) LIKE "%carro%" AND
   CONCAT( title, " ", description, " ", author) LIKE "%verde%" AND
   CONCAT( title, " ", description, " ", author) LIKE "%amassado%"
```

(quebras de linha adicionadas para facilitar a leitura)

Desta forma a pesquisa encontrará todos esses resultados:

```
O carro amassado era verde
A carroça tinha abacates verdes amassados
Verde carro, amassado tu és
```

Note que apesar de algumas linhas não terem resultados exatos, é melhor ter coisas a mais do que o usuário não encontrar o que precisa. Tenha em mente, no entanto, que o preço que se paga pela complexidade é uma pesquisa mais lenta. `LIKE` e índices não trabalham bem juntos.

Comment: Muito boam dica. Estou fazendo algumas adaptações e testando. assim que concluir posto o código completo e o resultado. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Estou tentando agora aplicar isso ao Framework Kohana.

Comment: Esse modo clássico utilizo muito.
Aconselho o uso "complementar" do "CASE WHEN" para ordenar a resposta da pesquisa. Exemplo, "começa com", "termina com", "começa com + espaço no inicio", "começa com + espaço no fim", "possui %string%"... e por aí vai..

Comment: Uma correção, trocar:
$palavras = $array_filter($palavras);
por
$palavras = array_filter($palavras); 
Valeu pela excelente dica  @Bacco, me ajudou e muito.

Comment: @adventistapr corrigido nessa e na outra parecida ;)

Comment: Considero o replace de "espaços" por % nos termos do que fazer uso de muitos likes e usar apenas um LIKE '%carros%verdes%amassados%'

Comment: @EliseuB. mas é por isso que a sua outra pergunta foi linkada para esta aqui, seu problema com a ordem das palavras é pelo fato de estar usando apenas um like para várias. `LIKE '%carros%verdes%amassados%'` nunca corresponderá a `carros amassados verdes`, pois o % significa "qualquer sequência de caracteres", nada mais, nada menos.

Comment: @Bacco mas isso seria uma particularidade da aplicação né? Em um comércio eletrônico se pesquiso "carros verdes amassados" e me retorna "abacates verdes amassados em papinha", não seria bem o que espero receber de resposta.

Comment: @EliseuB. agora já entramos num problema de interpretação de texto. Se uma palavra só basta, você usa OR. se quer as três, usa AND. E se não gostou da resposta, basta não usar ué. Pra hoje é o que eu tenho a oferecer como solução, ou então o fulltext, como linkei no outro post nos comments.

Comment: @Bacco isso mesmo de acordo, creio que com isso e com todas as orientações já posso implementar o código de modo conciso e mais eficiente, gratidão.

Comment: Veja o  índice fulltext na documentação do DB desejado, pode ser uma alternativa mais agradável (ele já faz automático essa coisa sem precisar de um monte de like) - Mas nem por isso significa que não tenha um peso de performance. O melhor é testar. Palavras chave: FTS, ou Full Text Index / Full Text Search

Answer (score 0):

Minha opinião, é ter somente um LIKE em sua consulta, e vc pode ainda manter dois campos no seu sistema, onde um campo seria o objeto ("Carro", "Moto", ..., ...) e no outro campo seria uma característica ("Verde", "Velha", ..., ...), depois quando for consultar, vc iria concatenar esse dois campos para colocar em sua query.

Ex:
valor_um = objeto;
valor_dois = característica;
valor_consulta = valor_um + valor_dois
campo LIKE "' + valor_consulta + "'%";

Ou deixar como estar e usar a porcentagem (%) no like dos dois lados, que vc com certeza vai achar alguma coisa tanto no campo um ou no campo dois.

espero q ajude.

Comment: Eu precisaria de algo mais objetivo para o usuário não ter que digitar dois campos, entende ? Atualmente o sistema está todo desenvolvido com a característica de apenas um campo para a busca. Infelizmente.