# Sistema de busca - Select dentro de outro

Tags: php, mysql, query, algoritmo-de-busca

Olá, estou fazendo um sistema de buscas, mas sou meio leigo a respeito de querys.
O método que pensei para refinar a busca, que no caso seria uma busca simples entre dois campos de uma tabela com vários produtos, foi de ir eliminando através de selects.

```
$varBusca = str_replace(array(',',' ','.','%','-','/','\\'),'-',$_POST['busca']);
$varBusca = explode('-',$varBusca);
/*  metodo 1 */
$query_busca="";
$pos_busca=0;
foreach($varBusca as $chave)
{
    if ($pos_busca==0){
        $query_busca.="SELECT * FROM ( # ) WHERE pro_nome LIKE '%$chave%' OR pro_descricao LIKE '%$chave%'";
    }else{
        $query_inserida="SELECT * FROM ( # ) WHERE pro_nome LIKE '%$chave%' OR pro_descricao LIKE '%$chave%'";
        $query_busca=str_replace('#',$query_inserida,$query_busca);
    }
    $pos_busca++;
}
$query_busca=str_replace('#','produtos',$query_busca);
echo $query_busca;
```

Eu quebro a string de busca e procuro por cada palavra.
Mas essa query acaba que me retornando nenhum item da tabela, mesmo que haja algum item com o alguma palavra da query.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Porque é que usas o `( # )`? Não era mais fácil por logo o nome da tabela em questão? Além disso pelo que me parece as *querys* são iguais. Ao certo não percebi bem o que pretendes com esse código.

Comment: @JorgeB. pelo visto não entendeu meu código... eu pego o valor de um campo input (caixa de busca) e quebro para pegar as palavras separadas. Eu quero pegar da tabela somente os itens que contenham todas as palavras digitadas, independente da ordem... logo coloco um select dentro de outro select. E adiciono automaticamente... mas já resolvi. Tive apenas que usar aliases. Nomear o select como uma tabela temporaria.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adaptei esta solução de uma [outra resposta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13179/). A idéia é usar o PHP para dividir a sua pesquisa em palavras separadas, e gerar a clausula WHERE pra você, mas de uma maneira que você já tenha uma query que busque todas as palavras de uma vez:

```
<?php

   $pesquisa = str_replace( array( ',', '.', '%', '-', '/', '\\' ),' ', $_POST['busca'] );
   $palavras = explode( ' ', $pesquisa ); // dividindo as palavras pelo espaço
   $palavras = array_filter($palavras); // eliminando ítens vazios

   $query = 'SELECT * FROM produtos ';
   $cola = 'WHERE ';

   //Aqui você pode juntar vários campos no concat.
   $campo = 'CONCAT( pro_nome, " ", pro_descricao)';

   foreach ($palavras as $palavra) {
      $palavra = trim($palavra); //Removendo espaços em branco
      $palavra = mysql_real_escape_string($palavra); //Precisa da conexao com o banco!
      $query .= $cola.campo.' LIKE "%'.$palavra.'%" ';
      $cola = 'AND ';
   }

   echo htmlentities( $query );
?>
```

E o resultado ao pesquisar `lápis azul 3b` será:

```
SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE
   CONCAT( pro_nome, " ", pro_descricao) LIKE "%lápis%" AND
   CONCAT( pro_nome, " ", pro_descricao) LIKE "%azul%" AND
   CONCAT( pro_nome, " ", pro_descricao) LIKE "%3b%"
```

(quebras de linha adicionadas para facilitar a leitura)

Desta forma a pesquisa encontrará todos esses resultados:

```
Lápis azul 3b
Lápis 3b azul-claro
Lápis azulado 3bcd
```

Note que apesar de algumas linhas não terem resultados exatos, é melhor ter coisas a mais do que o usuário não encontrar o que precisa. Tenha em mente, no entanto, que o preço que se paga pela complexidade é uma pesquisa ligeiramente mais lenta.

Comment: Não conheço muito as funções sql, de acordo com a necessidade vou aprendendo e esse CONCAT é realmente muito útil, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Obrigado Bacco. Tive que usar o seu código num sistema que estou aprimorando aqui e me ajudou bastante. Só tive que converter para ASP.

Comment: Pode melhorar com um order by e case // order by ( (case when pro_descricao) LIKE "%lápis%" then 1 else 0 end)+case when pro_descricao) LIKE "%azul%" then 1 else 0 end)+case when pro_descricao) LIKE "%3b%" then 1 else 0 end) ) Desc os melhorescresultados vem antes

Comment: @Motta eu até faço coisa do tipo em algumas situações. O booleano no My ja pode ser usado como numérico, então basta `(a LIKE '%a%') + ( b LIKE '%b%') ...` para rankear. O MySQL ainta teria o `IF( expressao, resultadoseverdadeiro, resultadosefalso)` pra encurtar a sintaxe em casos mais complexos. No SQLite fica mais interessante pq dá pra fazer uma "coluna virtual' com o placar de acertos e usar no WHERE coluna > 0. Eu preciso editar o post e comentar sobre FTS qualquer hora, pq se for complicar demais, o overhead desse monte de like acaba ficando caro e o FTS pode ser uma alternativa.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se consegui entender direito o que você está querendo.

Você tem um campo de busca, onde um usuário pode digitar "Um texto qualquer no campo" e na busca você quer trazer todos os registros que em determinado campo contenha uma das palavras do campo ("Um", "texto", "qualquer", "no", "campo")?

Se for isso, você pode fazer assim:

$search = explode(" ", $_POST["search"]);

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tabela";

foreach ( $search as $key => $value ){

    if ( $key == 0 ){
        $strSQL .= " WHERE ";
    }else{
        $strSQL .= " OR ";
    }

    $strSQL .= "campo like '%{$value}%'";

}
```

desse modo, supondo que o texto digitado no campo de busca seja "Um texto qualquer no campo", o valor da variável **$strSQL** será:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo like '%Um%' OR campo like '%texto%' OR campo like '%qualquer%' OR campo like '%no%' OR campo like '%campo%'
```

Comment: Eu repostei a solução que já tinha pronta em uso, que já estava pronta e é mais complexa, e abrange o caso da busca ser em mais de um campo, conforme o autor mencionou. De qq forma vc levou meu +1 por já ter respondido antes dando um caminho inicial correto.