# Como pesquisar um termo em mais de um campo em tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Como posso pesquisar um termo em mais de um campo de uma tabela no MySQL?
Por exemplo, tenho um site de uma loja de móveis e o cliente pode procurar pelo termo "cadeira" e esse termo está nos campos descrição, resumo e detalhes, gostaria de buscar em todos os campos.
Li alguma coisa sobre o select * from all_tables, mas nãpo consegui chegar no que preciso.

Comment: você conhece o phpmyadmin nele tem um campo de pesquisa e nele e possível efetuar consulta em mais de um campo, execute uma consulta nele e veja a saída do sql o resto e moleza

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normalmente basta pesquisar no resultado de todos os termos concatenados:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   tabela
WHERE
   CONCAT_WS( ' ', campo1,  campo2,  campo3,  campo4 ) LIKE '%termo%'
```

Se está procurando um jeito de procurar vários termos, temos algumas semi-duplicatas no site com solução pronta:

- [Busca com LIKE ou MATCH..AGAINST em duas colunas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13179/)
- [Sistema de busca - Select dentro de outro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15242/)

PS: Mesmo que os dados estejam em tabelas diferentes, o `CONCAT` funciona, desde que seja feito o `JOIN` adequado.

Comment: Obrigado @Bacco pelas excelentes dicas e sugestões, estou fazendo testes com todas elas e o retorno tem sido de qual modo excelente.