# Algoritmo para coincidir departamento, categoria e subcategoria de um BD com uma string recebida?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, algoritmo, select

A partir de uma string não padronizada, às vezes recebo o equivalente a departamento/categoria, às vezes equivalente a categoria/subcategoria, as vezes equivalente a departamento/subcategoria, as vezes departamento/categoria/subcategoria... etc...

...preciso criar uma consulta SQL para uma tabela padronizada com departamento, categoria e subcategoria para retornar as possíveis categorias que mais coincidem com a string recebida.

Estou quebrando a cabeça mas não consegui encontrar ainda um caminho eficiente para fazer esse tipo de consulta.

Alguém teria como me ajudar a pensar em um algoritmo eficiente que possa resolver esse tipo de problema?

**Exemplo**

```
string recebida = Camisetas/Masculino
```

Exemplo de uma linha da tabela do MySQL:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
|   Departamento    |    Categoria      | Subcategoria |
--------------------------------------------------------
| Moda e Acessórios | Roupas Masculinas |   Camisetas  |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Comecei o script PHP com um explode na string recebida para pegar o primeiro item do array como departamento, o segundo como categoria e o terceiro (quando existe) como sub-categoria porém não está parecendo um bom caminho.

Depois faz a inflexão dos termos.

Então, por último faço uma comparação usando a função nativa do PHP  similar_text()

Porém não estou tendo resultados muito satisfatórios.

Existe algum pattern para esses casos? Qualquer ideia será muito bem vinda.

Comment: Creio que eu já vi (e já respondi) algumas perguntas nesse sentido. Uma saída é gerar uma query com vários LIKE, um para cada palavra. Veja se é alguma coisa assim: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15810/70 - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38293/70 - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13179/70