# SELECT com PDO e variável

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, select

Como é possível fazer um SELECT em MYSQL com PDO próximo a isso abaixo:

```
$buscarNoticiaTitulo = "noticias.titulo LIKE '%teste%'";
$sqlNoticias = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE :buscarNoticiaTitulo');
$sqlNoticias->execute(array("buscarNoticiaTitulo" => $buscarNoticiaTitulo));
$resultadoSqlNoticias = $sqlNoticias->fetchAll();
```

O exemplo acima não da nenhum erro, mas também não retorna nada. Se eu fizer sem PDO ele retorna a notícia com o título "Teste 123 teste testando"

Answer (score 2):

Não use aspa simples na consulta `noticias.titulo LIKE '%teste%`, passe os coringas no `execute()` e monte corretamente a consulta o like fica fora do placeholder.

```
$buscarNoticiaTitulo = "valor";
$sqlNoticias = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE noticias.titulo LIKE :buscarNoticiaTitulo');
$sqlNoticias->execute(array("buscarNoticiaTitulo" => '%'. $buscarNoticiaTitulo .'%'));
```

Comment: O problema é que a variável $buscarNoticiaTitulo recebe vários valores de uma array, ai eu ia montando ela assim:
  
`$buscarNoticiaTitulo = "noticias.titulo LIKE '%teste%' OR noticias.titulo LIKE '%orelha%'"`

Ela pode receber infinitas palavras, de acordo com a busca do usuário... @rray

Comment: @caiocafardo precisa mudar toda a lógica, para gerar o placeholder e montar os `OR`s, pera ai

Comment: @caiocafardo talvez essa pergunta ajude: [Sistema de busca - Select dentro de outro](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15810/91)

Comment: Tem algum erro na resposta? posso corrigir.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, acabei conseguindo dessa forma:

```
$buscarNoticiaTitulo = "noticias.titulo LIKE '%teste%'";
$sqlNoticias = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE '.$buscarNoticiaTitulo.'');
$sqlNoticias->execute();
$resultadoSqlNoticias = $sqlNoticias->fetchAll();
```

Não sei se é a forma mais correta, mas funciona. Depois vou ver com calma essa questão e se souber de algo mais correto posto aqui!

Answer (score 0):

```
$teste = 'noticia tal';

$sqlNoticias = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE titulo LIKE :titulo');
$sqlNoticias->execute(array(
 ':titulo' => '%'.$teste.'%'
));

$resultado = $sqlNoticias->fetchAll();
```