# Like postgres PDO com foreach

Tags: php, pdo

to precisando usar um like em foreach mas sem sucesso, fiz da seguinte forma:

```
$arr = array('\'%a%\'', '\'%b%\'', '\'%c%\'');
foreach ($arr as $a){
   $this->SQL = "update client set active=1 where date between ? and ? and type like ?"
   $this->SQL =$this->PDO->prepare($this->SQL);
   $this->SQL->execute(array($this->Since, $this->Until, $a));
}
```

O ele executa mas não realiza o update, tentei com var_dump ver o que ocorria, mas não obtive sucesso. Alguém que tenha passado por isso e conseguido resolver?

Obrigado =]

Comment: Obrigado pela colaboração, mas só errei na hora de passar aqui o exemplo, no code original esta com o 'and'. abç

Comment: vc tbm não precisa escapar os coringas, [veja](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115248/91)

Comment: sem escape retorna assim (meu exemplo de produção): Array ( [0] => 42601 [1] => 7 [2] => ERROR: syntax error at or near "$3" LINE 1: ...t = 0 where cmdatecreate between $1 and $2 and cmtext in $3 ^ )

Comment: Ele diz que o erro está no valor passado para o like ou antes.

Comment: $1 e $2 sei que não está o problema, no terceiro passo como ta o array acima sem os escape, to tentando com foreach ( $arr as $a => $value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso alguém passe pelo mesmo problema segue como eu consegui resolver:

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c');
foreach ($arr as $a){
   $this->SQL = "update client set active=1 where date between ? and ? and type like ?"
   $this->SQL =$this->PDO->prepare($this->SQL);
   $this->SQL->execute(array($this->Since, $this->Until, '%'.$a.'%'));
}
```

sendo necessário apenas passar as "%" no array dos parâmetros.

Valeu pra quem contribuiu.