# Como pesquisar por múltiplos termos independente de ordem?

Tags: php, sql

o meu cenário e o seguinte, tenho um input onde o usuário coloca o termo e clica em pesquisa

EX: carro horizonte [ENTER]

o porem e que esta listando o resultado das palavras separados

EX: 3 resultados encontrados

id1 - casa em belo horizonte

id2 - aceita carro na troca

id3- carro localizado em belo horizonte

gostaria que exibisse somente o resultado que contenha as 2 palavras

EX: 1 resultado encontrado

id1- carro localizado em belo horizonte

```
?>
$search_term = filter_var($_GET["s"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$palavras = explode(" ", $search_term);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($palavras); $i++) 
$q = "SELECT * FROM classificados WHERE texto LIKE '%".$palavras[$i]."%' AND aprovado='s' ORDER BY ID desc";
$r = mysql_query($q);
if(mysql_num_rows($r)==0)//no result found
{
echo "<div id='search-status'>Nenhum resultado encontrado!</div>";
}
else //result found
{
echo "<ul>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
    {
    $title = $row['texto'];
?>
```

espero ter ilustrado bem minha duvida

Comment: Se entendi bem a pergunta você teria, que colocar cada palavra em um like tipo isso:
"SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE texto LIKE '%".$palavras1."%' AND LIKE '%".$palavras2."%' AND aprovado='s' ORDER BY ID desc"; é mais ou menos isso ?

Comment: Não é isso aqui que vc quer? Se for, já está praticamente pronto o código na resposta. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13181/70

Comment: diego segue    $palavras = explode(" ", $search_term);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($palavras); $i++) 
$q = "SELECT * FROM classificados WHERE texto = '%".$palavras[$i]."%' AND aprovado='s' ORDER BY ID desc";

Comment: Em partes é verdade @Bacco, mas ele pode estar querendo o tratamento para dividir as duas palavras do input.

Comment: vi sim Diego porem a busca é apenas em um campo ( texto) nesse resultado o proprio like ja fazia, e o que gostaria era de somente listar os resultados que contenham as palavras chaves no mesmo texto

Comment: Veja se ajuda  http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/509139-encontrar-a-palavra-como-ela-foi-digitada/

Comment: boa Motta achei que esse problema era mais simples de resolver, mais dei uma olhada por alto em MATCH AGAINST e pode ser isso que va resolver mesmo porem vou deixar pra estudar amanha essa parte pois estou comencando agora

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segue modificação no seu loop para montar a query:

```
 $search_term = filter_var( $_GET['s'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
 $palavras = explode( ' ', $search_term );
 $q = 'SELECT * FROM classificados WHERE';
 for ( $i = 0; $i < count($palavras); $i++ ) { 
    $q .= " texto LIKE '%" . $palavras[$i] . "%' AND " ;
 }
 $q .= " aprovado='s' ORDER BY ID desc";
 $r = mysql_query( $q );

 if( mysql_num_rows( $r )==0 ...
```

Se preferir a busca exata que não pegue `carros` em vez de `carro`, basta usar assim:

```
 $search_term = filter_var( $_GET['s'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
 $palavras = explode( ' ', $search_term );
 $q = 'SELECT * FROM classificados WHERE';
 for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $palavras ); $i++ ) { 
    $q .= " CONCAT( \" \", texto, \" \" ) LIKE '% " . $palavras[$i] . " %' AND "; 
 }
 $q .= " aprovado='s' ORDER BY ID desc";
 $r = mysql_query($q);
```

Tenha o cuidado neste caso de manter os espaços como estão no código.

Comment: realmente era isso mesmo