# SQL Like sem considerar a ordem dos parâmetros

Tags: sql, parâmetros

Eu preciso fazer uma comparação entre duas tabelas pra descobrir se o endereço da tabela A está presente no endereço da tabela B.

Exemplo: A tabela A tem um registro com o campo ENDERECO com o valor "RUA FULANO DE TAL 67 401" e na tabela B, o campo ENDERECO comtém "RUA FULANO DE TAL, AP 401, 67". Ou seja, ela contém tudo que eu procuro, mas em uma ordem diferente. O SQL

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA_B WHERE ENDERECO LIKE '%RUA%FULANO%DE%TAL%67%401%'
```

não retorna nada, porque o SELECT procura os parâmetros na ordem informada.

Agora a minha pergunta: **Existe uma maneira de pesquisar por todos os parâmetros, independente da ordem que eles foram inseridos?**

Comment: O que você está tentando fazer é extremamente difícil. Há empresas que comercializam (e não é barato) rotinas para normalização de endereços, as quais pegam endereços iguais, mas escritos de forma diferente (abreviações, posição do número, do complemento, etc.) e transformam em um modelo único, normalizado, que pode ser comparado por igualdade, ou por percentual de semelhança. Resumindo: não é uma implementação simples. A solução dada por Bacco, baseada no algoritmo simples que você está implementando, funcionará, mas não espere resultados muito satisfatórios!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente é só separar as condições:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   TABELA_B
WHERE
   ENDERECO LIKE '%RUA%'
   AND ENDERECO LIKE '%FULANO%'
   AND ENDERECO LIKE '%DE%'
   AND ENDERECO LIKE '%TAL%'
   AND ENDERECO LIKE '%67%'
   AND ENDERECO LIKE '%401%'
```

Aqui explico como gerar dinamicamente este tipo de *query*:

> [Como pesquisar por múltiplos termos independente de ordem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35487/70)

Para gerar dinamicamente este tipo de *query*, a lógica é sempre a mesma: separar por palavras, acrescentar campo `LIKE '%palavra%'` para cada uma, unidos por `AND` (ou por `OR` se quiser a busca por qualquer um dos termos). Coisa de meia dúzia de linhas na maioria das linguagens.

Só não se esqueça de sanitizar as *strings* para evitar injeção de SQL (isto independe da técnica usada, o código original já sofre desta vulnerabilidade).

Caso REALMENTE precise fazer isto nativamente (em muitos casos não justifica), precisa ver se o referido DB tem o recurso de colunas com suporte a `Full Text`:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search

Já adianto que para boa parte dos casos, a solução da *query* montada é mais simples e prática, e não requer conhecimentos mais complexos. *Full-text search* já requer repensar um pouco na arquitetura da aplicação.

Comment: Bacco, obrigado pela resposta. Foi ótima, porém não em atende e eu explico porque:

Comment: Respondi considerando tudo que está no corpo da pergunta.

Comment: Na verdade o texto "RUA FULANO DE TAL 67 401" está salvo no banco no campo ENDERECO da tabela A. Eu uso ele no Select dando um Replace substituindo os espaços por %. Eu não consigo então montar o SQL passando um parâmetro pra cada palavra ou termo a ser pesquisado.

Comment: Desse seu jeito não funciona. Como disse, precisa fazer os LIKE dinamicamente (tem outras maneiras, mas todas mais complexas, creio eu). Se você usa alguma linguagem para o replace, poderia fazer o mesmo criando os LIKE, não? Não que seja impossível fazer com SQL, mas é uma complicação desnecessária se estiver usando alguma linguagem extra.

Comment: O exemplo que eu passei no link é PHP, mas a lógica pode facilmente ser adaptada pra qualquer linguagem. O link é mera referência. A lógica é sempre a mesma: separar por palavras, acrescentar `campo LIKE '%palavra%'` para cada uma, unidos por `AND`. Coisa de 4 ou 5 linhas na maioria das linguagens, um pouco mais se quiser fazer alguma sanitização extra.