# Problema com busca por palavras chave, em MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

O problema é: Como eu posso fazer para executar uma busca de resultados por palavra-chave contidas separadamente no banco?

Ex: Eu busco por "CARROS VERMELHOS".  O php executa a query "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo LIKE '%$keyWords%'"

O problema é: Nessa consulta, retornaria apenas resultados com as palavras em sequência, como eu digitei "CARROS VERMELHOS". Se eu tiver um resultado tipo "Fotos de CARROS  brancos e VERMELHOS", a busca não irá indexar esse resultado, mesmo contendo as palavras-chave que informei... Como resolver isso? Pesquisar por palavras-chave mesmo independente da ordem e se estão separadas por outras palavras, como a google faz?

Comment: Coloque o % entre as palavras também: "%CARROS%VERMELHOS%"

Comment: E também tem essa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15242/70

Comment: Outra variação do problema: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35487/70