# Como encontrar um valor em diversos campos

Tags: sql, sql-server

No meu banco tenho 3 colunas para telefone, preciso saber se o valor esta em algum dos 3 campos, qual é a melhor forma para montar esse select?

Comment: Não diretamente pro caso em questão, mas para quem for usar solução do tipo com alguma linguagem auxiliar, segue um exemplo de como automatizo buscas em vários campos e com várias strings: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13181/70

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar um `IN` "ao contrário" (do que se usa normalmente):

```
... WHERE '2345-6789' IN (tel1, tel2, tel3)
```

Comment: A cláusula está absolutamente correta, mas é como se estivesse ao contrário, me deu até vertigem. Parece que estou olhando uma imagem de cabeça para baixo, tanto é o costume de usar o campo à esquerda e valores fixos à direita do `IN`.  (:

Answer (score 3):

Se for uma busca não exata, isto é, por números que contém um trecho do telefone, pode fazer assim:

```
WHERE telefone1 like '%123%'
    OR telefone2 like '%123%'
    OR telefone3 like '%123%'
```

Sendo `123` o número digitado pelo usuário no campo de busca.

Comment: NO MySQL costumo usar CONCAT( telefone1, ' ', telefone2, ' ', telefone3 ) LIKE '%123%' (tem o concat_ws tambem, pra por o espaço uma vez só, mas comentei do "tradicional" por ser mais comum nos vários SGBDs).

Comment: @Bacco Havia pensado no `CONCAT`. Estou curioso para saber sobre a diferença de desempenho entre as duas soluções. Mas um possível problema é que se o usuário puder digitar o caractere separador, há possibilidade da consulta retornar um falso positivo envolvendo o final e o início de dois telefones.

Comment: de fato isto tem que ser utilizado com cuidado. O ideal é realmente escolher um separador "especial". Usualmente eu associo isso a um split pelo próprio separador, por isso no meu caso concreto não dá efeito colateral; Sobre a resposta do @bfavaretto, eu realmente acho interessante toda e qualquer alternativa que economize o like, quando trata-se em substring. A sua eu acho interessante como orientação geral. Preciso até revisar umas respostas minhas pra otimizar para SGBDs específicos.