# Busca de termos "fora de ordem" no texto em PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou montando um simples sistema de busca para um banco de artigos de um evento científico estudantil. Adaptando códigos de alguns guias que achei na internet o sistema está funcionando todo certinho. O único problema é que ele só retorna resultados com palavras exatas.

Por exemplo: Se eu quiser retornar um artigo que fale sobre Organização da Informação e pesquisar por "Organização Informação", o sistema não retorna nada. O usuário precisa por na busca exatamente "Organização da Informação".

Encontrei um tópico aqui no Stack que me parece conter a solução do problema nas respostas, no entanto, não consegui aplicar no meu sistema. Segue o link: [Busca com LIKE ou MATCH..AGAINST em duas colunas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13179/busca-com-like-ou-match-against-em-duas-colunas)

Peço que analisem meu código e me auxiliem, se possível, em como encaixar as dicas no meu sistema ou se tiver um modo melhor de fazer, que por favor me deem uma luz.

Segue o código PHP que estou utilizando para a busca (Removi apenas os códigos relativos à paginação dos resultados):

```
<?php
// A busca
$busca = $_GET['consulta'];
$busca = mysql_real_escape_string($busca);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `artigos` WHERE (`ativa` = 1) AND ((`titulo` LIKE '%".$busca."%') OR (`resumo` LIKE '%".$busca."%') OR ('%".$busca."%')) ORDER BY `grupo` DESC LIMIT ".$inicio.", ".$_BS['PorPagina'];

// Executa a consulta
$query = mysql_query($sql);

// Mostra resultados
echo "<ul>";
while ($resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$titulo = $resultado['titulo'];
$resumo = $resultado['resumo'];
$link = 'http://meusite.com.br/artigos/' . $resultado['link'];
echo "<li>";
echo '<a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$titulo.'">'.$titulo.'</a><br />';
echo "<p>";
echo '<p>'.$resumo.'</p>';
echo "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";

?>
```

Desde já, agradeço a ajuda.

Abraços!

Comment: Exatamente tens aqui a solução: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13181/7210 onde estás a ter dificuldade.

Comment: Jorge, mencionei justamente este link na minha dúvida. O problema é que não funcionou. Utilizei da seguinte maneira: Substituí a string "$pesquisa = 'carro verde amassado ';" por "$pesquisa = $busca".

Comment: Esse link é o mesmo para o seu problema, quando vc implementou chegou a dar algum resultado?

Comment: Tentei trocar o AND por OR, mas nada. Continua apenas retornando os termos exatos. Se alguma palavra estiver entre eles, a busca não retorna nada.

Answer (score 2):

O problema era apenas falta de conhecimento em PHP, mas após muitas tentativas modificando o código do link acima, consegui. Segue o resultado para que outros com a mesma dúvida consigam fazer.

```
<?php
// A busca
// Salva o que foi buscado em uma variável
$pesquisa = str_replace( array( ',', '.', '%', '-', '/', '\\' ),' ', $_GET['consulta'] );
// Usa a função mysql_real_escape_string() para evitar erros no MySQL
$pesquisa = mysql_real_escape_string($pesquisa);
$palavras = explode( ' ', $pesquisa ); // dividindo as palavras pelo espaço
$palavras = array_filter($palavras); // eliminando ítens vazios

// Monta a consulta 
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM artigos ';
$cola = 'WHERE ';

//Aqui você pode juntar vários campos no concat.
$campo = 'CONCAT( titulo, " ", resumo)';

foreach ($palavras as $palavra) {
$palavra = trim($palavra); //Removendo espaços em branco
$palavra = mysql_real_escape_string($palavra); //Precisa da conexão com o banco!
$sql .= $cola.campo.' LIKE "%'.$palavra.'%" ';
$cola = 'AND ';
}
// Executa a consulta
$query = mysql_query($sql);

// Mostra resultados
echo "<ul>";
while ($resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$titulo = $resultado['titulo'];
$resumo = $resultado['resumo'];
$link = 'http://meusite.com.br/artigos/' . $resultado['link'];
echo "<li>";
echo '<a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$titulo.'">'.$titulo.'</a><br />';
echo "<p>";
echo '<p>'.$resumo.'</p>';
echo "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";

?>
```

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Abraços.